# DropDownList To be Selected on Edit using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm trying to populate the edit view with data which has dropdownlists using ViewModel . The data populates but the Dropdownlists are not selected as per the data.

Have checked similar issues in SO like [SO1][1] , [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579407/set-the-selected-item-in-dropdownlist-in-mvc3) , [SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654873/asp-net-mvc-4-viewmodel-with-dropdownlist-data) but not able to resolve . Know it might be something silly I'm missing but unable to find.

Code: 
Viewmodel:

```
 public class ProductVM
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Product Name")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public int SupplierID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

        public int UnitID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  Units { get; set; }
        public Unit Unit { get; set; }

        public int ItemCategoryID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Categories")]
        public ItemCategory ItemCategory { get; set; }
     }
Controller Edit :
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var productVM = GetProductById(id);


            return View(productVM);
        }
 private ProductVM GetProductById(int id)
        {
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);

            var productVM = new ProductVM();


           var suppliers = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "ID", "SupplierName", product.SupplierID);
            productVM.Suppliers = suppliers.ToList();

            var categories = new SelectList(db.ItemCategories, "ID", "Name", product.ItemCategoryID);
            productVM.Categories = categories.ToList();

  var units = new SelectList(db.Units, "ID", "Name", product.UnitID);
            productVM.Units = units.ToList();
        }
```

View :

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierID, "SupplierID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.SupplierID, Model.Suppliers, "--Select--")

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitID, "UnitID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.UnitID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Units, "--Select--")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnitID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemCategoryID, "ItemCategoryID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.ItemCategoryID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Categories, "--Select--")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemCategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.
      [1]: [Binding Viewmodel Property to dropdown selected item in razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917916/binding-viewmodel-property-)

to-dropdown-selected-item-in-razor

Comment: Are you saying you want the dropdownlists to load with values already selected? Like with this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to set an initial value into your selected values in the controller before passing the model to the view if you want the dropdownlists to load with a pre-selected value. For example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var productVM = GetProductById(id);
    //Set your pre-determined values here and they will show up on the view once binded
    productVM.SupplierID = 1;
    productVM.UnitID = 1;
    productVM.ItemCategoryID  = 1;

    return View(productVM);
}
```

This question does a great job of breaking that process down: [How to get DropDownList SelectedValue in Controller in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you set in the `selectedValue` parameter in the `SelectList` is going to be ignored. Why? Because you have a [strongly typed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views) and you are binding `SupplierID` property of `ProductVM` to the dropdown. In your `GetProductById` method, you are not actually populating the `productVM.SupplierID`, `UnitID` and `ItemCategoryID`. So they will have the default int value, `0`.

So you can change you method to this:

```
private ProductVM GetProductById(int id)
{
    Product product = db.Products.Find(id);

    var productVM = new ProductVM
    {
        // No need to pass the 4th parameter "selectedValue" in SelectList. 
        Suppliers = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "ID", "SupplierName"),
        Categories = new SelectList(db.ItemCategories, "ID", "Name"),
        Units = new SelectList(db.Units, "ID", "Name"),

        // Populate these properties
        SupplierID = product.SupplierID,
        ItemCategoryID = product.ItemCategoryID,
        UnitID = product.UnitID
    };

    return productVM ;
}
```

The optional `selectedValue` parameter is usually used when we're not using strongly typed `view`s. If you were to change your View to the following, then your dropdown would have pre selected the value:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Supplier", Model.Suppliers, "--Select--")
```

Comment: Thanks adiga for your time and the clear explanation